# Sum totals of two queries

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I have two basic queries which I need to sum the totals of:

```
Select hours, sum(hours) FROM table WHERE name='xxx' and Description='Worked'
Select hours2, sum(hours2) FROM table WHERE name='xxx' and Description2='Worked'
```

I've tried UNION and it will get me the totals of each query but it will not combine them.

Table setup is:

- ID
- name
- hours
- description
- hours2
- description2

I need to correlate hours to description and hours2 to description2 which is why I have the two different queries. I need to sum the totals of hours and hours2.

Comment: Are they the same columns from the same table? Or is it really `hour` and `hour2`?

Comment: Looks like your table isn't normalised.

Comment: @Jason-There is hours and hours2. 

@OMG- Yes (i think). Hours is related to description as Hours2 is related to description2.

Comment: Please post a sample of the table data and a sample of the output you expect- it isn't clear. Since you have no `GROUP BY`, these queries are likely not giving you determinate results for the `hours` and `hours2` columns.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

First of all, you missed `group by`, so even though mysql doesn't complain about it, you `hours` and `hours2` values are meaningless. 
Secondly, you the result of `UNION` can be put in derived subquery, so you will have the desired total :

```
SELECT SUM(hr) FROM
(
  Select sum(hours) as hr FROM table WHERE name='xxx' and Description='Worked'
  UNION ALL
  Select sum(hours2) as hr FROM table WHERE name='xxx' and Description2='Worked'
)a
```

Comment: Good or bad, MySQL won't complain about the lack of GROUP BY by design: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html

Comment: @OMG Ponies: I didn't say it's a bad feature (sometimes it's very useful), I just pointed out that in such context the values of non-aggregate are meaningless.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm very new to this so the structure is probably way off.

What is the 'a' for at the end? I had tried that exact query before but with the 'a'.

Comment: @This Guy: The `a` at the end is a table alias -- most databases require one is defined for a derived table/inline view like you see in Alex's answer

Answer (score 2):

You would need to place your union into a subquery:

```
SELECT  Hours,
        SUM(Hours) AS Hours,
        SUM(Hours2) AS Hours2
FROM    (   SELECT  Hours,
                    SUM(Hours) AS Hours,
                    0 AS Hours2
            FROM    Table
            WHERE   Name = 'xxx'
            AND     Description = 'Worked'
            GROUP BY Hours
            UNION ALL
            SELECT  Hours2,
                    0 AS Hours,
                    SUM(Hours2) AS Hours
            FROM    Table
            WHERE   Name = 'xxx'
            AND     Description2 = 'Worked'
            GROUP BY Hours2
        ) t
GROUP BY Hours;
```

Comment: @AvinashBabu at least he didn't steal his answer and no it wasn't helpful to you since this was never your question to begin with.